# Trix - undefined method `to_key'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, trix

I have a `CategoryForm` obejct for which I render a form and I installed Trix editor (`gem 'trix'`) to let my users format the text. After installing `Trix` I am getting `undefined method 'to_key'`. Here's my current setup.

#### app/assets/javascripts/admins/categories/categories.js

`//= require trix`

#### app/assets/stylesheets/admins/categories/categories.css

`*= require trix`

#### CategoryForm

```
class CategoryForm
  attr_accessor :short_desc_pl, :short_desc_en, :short_desc_de,
                :long_desc_pl, :long_desc_en, :long_desc_de,
                :resource

  def initialize(params = {})
    @resource = Category.find(params[:id])
    generate_fields
  end

  private

  def generate_fields
    @short_desc_pl = @resource.short_description['pl']
    @short_desc_en = @resource.short_description['en']
    @short_desc_de = @resource.short_description['de']
    @long_desc_pl = @resource.long_description['pl']
    @long_desc_en = @resource.long_description['en']
    @long_desc_de = @resource.long_description['de']
  end
end
```

#### Form

```
<%= form_for category_form, as: 'category', url: admins_category_path(category_form.resource), method: :patch do |form| %>
  
  <table class="table">
    <col>
    <colgroup span="2"></colgroup>
    <colgroup span="2"></colgroup>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">PL</th>
      <th scope="col">EN</th>
      <th scope="col">DE</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">Krótki opis</th>
      <td><%= form.text_field :short_desc_pl, class: 'form-control' %></td>
      <td><%= form.text_field :short_desc_en, class: 'form-control', required: true %></td>
      <td><%= form.text_field :short_desc_de, class: 'form-control', required: true %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">Długi opis</th>
      <td><%= form.trix_editor :long_desc_pl, size: "20x20", class: 'form-control', required: true %></td>
      <td><%= form.text_area :long_desc_en, size: "20x20", class: 'form-control', required: true %></td>
      <td><%= form.text_area :long_desc_de, size: "20x20", class: 'form-control', required: true %></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit 'Zapisz' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

What am I doing wrong?

#### UPDATE

I even changed my form to use @category

```
<%= form_for category, as: 'category', url: admins_category_path(category), method: :patch do |form| %>
...
```

and I am not getting any error but the editor simply does not render. I am using Webpacker, Rails 5.1.

Comment: What is the full error message?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev `undefined method `to_key' for <CategoryForm>`. After I render the form for `@category` the editor does not render at all.

Comment: "the editor does not render at all" - any errors in the browser console?

Comment: No, no errors at all. @SergioTulentsev